# how to display the name of a selected select with jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a drop-down list reminder by names CHANTIERS, and a button validate, I want when I click on button validate to display name CHANTIER selected, in my example it gives me value of CHANTIER selected but I want the name, help please me.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Select Chantier:</label>
      {!! Form::select('chantier_id',[''=>'--- Select Chantier ---']+$chantiers,null,array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'chan')) !!}
    </div>
```

span where I want to display it

```
<h4>chantier : <span id="ch"></span></h4>
```

code jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
  let value = $('#nbr').val();
  let valu = $('#datePicker').val();
  let valu1 = $('#chan').val();
    $('#dateE').text(valu);
    $('#ch').text(valu1);

  if (value == ""){
     $('#error').show();
  }else{
      $("#form1").hide();
       $("#form2").show();

       $('.input2').val(value);
   }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let valu1 = $('#chan').val();
```

To

```
let valu1 = $("#chan option:selected").html(); //or
let valu1 = $("#chan option:selected").text();
```